# Getting Atom Names in Bio.PDB

Tags: python, biopython, protein-database

I am trying to run a code using BioPython that will allow me to iterate through the atoms of multiple proteins and remove all hydrogen atoms from them. To identify which atoms correspond to hydrogen I wrote the following code:

```py
atom = residues[0].get_atoms()

atoms = list(atom)

atoms

[<Atom N>,
 <Atom CA>,
 <Atom C>,
 <Atom O>,
 <Atom CB>,
 <Atom OG1>,
 <Atom CG2>,
 <Atom H1>,
 <Atom H2>,
 <Atom H3>,
 <Atom HA>,
 <Atom HB>,
 <Atom HG1>,
 <Atom HG21>,
 <Atom HG22>,
 <Atom HG23>]
```

How can I make it so that BioPython will return the name of the actual element of these atoms, such as "Carbon" or "Hydrogen"?

Note, I tried to use the following functions from the `Bio.PDB.Atom` module:

```
"get_name()",
```

```
"get_id"
```

```
"get_full_id"
```

They did not return the desired element name.

Comment: I think you would have to provide your own `name` to "English full name" lookup. This would be a locale thing. The [docs state](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.PDB.Atom.html) that `name` and `fullname` are both abbreviated to the element symbol.

Comment: atom.element should be the relevant attribute

Answer (score 2):

Atom's element is stored in:

```
atom.element
```

It's a string with periodic table element abbreviation: C and H rather than Carbon and Hydrogen.

Comment: usual abbreviation: does it mean periodic table element abbreviation ?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

You may need to translate the elements yourself. You can use the `periodictable` package.

Note that `biopython` uses upper-case e.g. `FE` for element names and `periodictable` uses title-case e.g. `Fe`.

I created two methods below: one that takes a symbol i.e. `symbol_to_english`, and another that takes the atom i.e. `atom_to_english` and passes its name to `symbol_to_english`.

```py
import periodictable as pt
from Bio.PDB.Atom import Atom

def symbol_to_english(symbol: str) -> str:
    """This function converts a symbol to its English name.

    Args:
        symbol (str): The symbol of the element.

    Returns:
        str: The English name of the element.
    """
    try:
        return pt.elements.isotope(symbol.title()).name.title()
    except Exception as exc:
        raise ValueError(f"Could not convert symbol {symbol} to English.") from exc

def atom_to_english(atom: Atom) -> str:
    """This function converts an atom's element to its English name.

    Args:
        atom (Atom): The atom to convert.

    Returns:
        str: The English name of the atom's element.
    """
    return symbol_to_english(atom.element)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    atoms = [Atom("FE", (1, 2, 3), 1.0, 1.0, "", "FE", 1, "FE")]
    names = [atom_to_english(atom) for atom in atoms]

    print(names)  # ['Iron']
```

Comment: this is if you dont get your protein from th rcsb pdb l(https://www.rcsb.org/) where pdbs contains the element that should be parsed by biopython like in : 'ATOM    465  CB  ARG A  61      14.237 -71.441   5.814  1.00141.31           C' where C stands for Carbon